# Missing portion when 3D printing (even if the 3D print tab seems OK), I need help to figure out what's happening

Tags: 3d-printing

I tried different approach and redid the model a couple of times and I always and up with the missing parts you see on the picture. I just don't understand why it's doing that. I've printed a lot of stuff and this never happen before.

[image: Model in Blender]

[image: Result]

Comment: Are the normals facing in the right direction? Check: Viewport Overlays (Top bar, click dropdown) -> Face Orientation. Red means normals are flipped and that might cofuse the slicer you are using. To fix it just go into edit mode, press A to select all and Ctrl+Shift+N to recalculate normals.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When checked, they showed blue like if they were OK. If I try Ctrl+Shift+N they become red.

Comment: As an additional information, I tried it with all faces red and all faces blue and both give me the same results. the same length is missing at the middle.

Comment: That is strange. Does the model show up fine in your slicer?

Comment: Yes it does, everything seems normal until its printing.